# Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: spring-boot, openldap, spring-ldap

I'm trying to manage user and groups of LDAP through a Spring Boot application and I'm referring from here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/tree/master/samples/user-admin but instead of using XML configuration, I used Java based configuration.

This is my current code https://github.com/wmfairuz/spring-ldap-user-admin

And this is my current error:

```
...
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.514  INFO 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.527  INFO 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'metricFilter' to: [/*]
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.533  INFO 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.534  INFO 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.544  INFO 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.545  INFO 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.547  INFO 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'webRequestLoggingFilter' to: [/*]
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.549  INFO 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.597 DEBUG 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Initializing filter 'requestContextFilter'
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.601 DEBUG 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.web.OrderedRequestContextFilter  : Filter 'requestContextFilter' configured successfully
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.605 DEBUG 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] iguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter : Initializing filter 'applicationContextIdFilter'
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.609 DEBUG 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] iguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter : Filter 'applicationContextIdFilter' configured successfully
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.613 DEBUG 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.b.c.w.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter : Initializing filter 'httpPutFormContentFilter'
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.615 DEBUG 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.b.c.w.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter : Filter 'httpPutFormContentFilter' configured successfully
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.616 DEBUG 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter      : Initializing filter 'metricFilter'
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.617 DEBUG 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter      : Filter 'metricFilter' configured successfully
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.627 DEBUG 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.w.OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter  : Initializing filter 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter'
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.631 DEBUG 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.w.OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter  : Filter 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' configured successfully
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.633 DEBUG 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.w.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter : Initializing filter 'characterEncodingFilter'
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.635 DEBUG 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.w.OrderedCharacterEncodingFilter : Filter 'characterEncodingFilter' configured successfully
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.638 DEBUG 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter      : Initializing filter 'webRequestLoggingFilter'
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.640 DEBUG 8824 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter      : Filter 'webRequestLoggingFilter' configured successfully
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.857  WARN 8824 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groupController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sample.domain.GroupRepo sample.controller.GroupController.groupRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groupRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.863  INFO 8824 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
    2015-12-22 18:18:39.889 ERROR 8824 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groupController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sample.domain.GroupRepo sample.controller.GroupController.groupRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groupRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113) [spring-boot-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
            at sample.UserApplication.main(UserApplication.java:19) [classes/:na]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
            at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:467) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar:1.3.1.RELEASE]
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_51]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sample.domain.GroupRepo sample.controller.GroupController.groupRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groupRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            ... 23 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groupRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            ... 25 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:185) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
            at org.springframework.ldap.repository.support.LdapRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LdapRepositoryFactoryBean.java:47) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
            ... 35 common frames omitted

    2015-12-22 18:18:39.905  INFO 8824 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [... too long...]
    [WARNING]
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
            at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:467)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groupController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sample.domain.GroupRepo sample.controller.GroupController.groupRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groupRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:764)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:357)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113)
            at sample.UserApplication.main(UserApplication.java:19)
            ... 6 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sample.domain.GroupRepo sample.controller.GroupController.groupRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groupRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
            ... 23 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groupRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
            ... 25 more
    Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object;
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:185)
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:251)
            at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:237)
            at org.springframework.ldap.repository.support.LdapRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LdapRepositoryFactoryBean.java:47)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
            ... 35 more
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 8.146 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-22T18:18:39+08:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 34M/386M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project spring-ldap-user-admin: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'groupController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private sample.domain.GroupRepo sample.controller.GroupController.groupRepo; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'groupRepo': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getTargetRepository(Lorg/springframework/data/repository/core/RepositoryInformation;)Ljava/lang/Object; -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your `GroupRepo` is interface without implementation. There is no bean to be autowired into `GroupController`. You need to create implementation of `GroupRepo` and mark that as `@Repository`.

**Reaction on comment:**
I am not familiar with **spring-ldap** library, but looking at the example code you follow, [GroupRepo interface](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/blob/05b89c3b45e63263c3b5667677f80ab5f70ed5bb/samples/user-admin/src/main/java/org/springframework/ldap/samples/useradmin/domain/GroupRepo.java) is not annotated with `@Repository`. So try to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did it like that because in the Spring LDAP sample they did put a note like this. "This one will never be referenced directly, but the ldap:repositories tag will make sure
        it will be 'wired in', because the GroupRepo interface extends from an interface that GroupRepoImpl
        imlements.". You can refer here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ldap/blob/master/samples/user-admin/src/main/resources/applicationContext.xml